# Respond to Stripe 200 Ok

Tags: java, playframework, stripe-payments

i need to send a 200 OK response to stripe whenever i receive an event successfully as mentioned in their documentation.
I am using Json. i do not know how to send 200 Ok using Json.
is this a correct way:

```
   ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("status","200 OK");
    return ok(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200 Ok :

```
return ok();
```

404 Not Found :

```
return notFound();
```

500 Internal Server Error :

```
return internalServerError();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok itself has 200 code, so, it's not necessary nor usual to return a json object.

According to play documentation

```
static Results.Status   ok() 
          Generates a 200 OK simple result.
```

Check [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html)